# How to include in Odoo?

Tags: templates, include, odoo, qweb

im a bit new in Odoo(internship) , so I wanted to know if there was an equivalence to include(php) in Odoo(qweb) ?

Otherwise, how can we include an xml file in another one?

For example, I got my main xml file and I want to call the different pages or parts of pages(by id or class) into my main page , is it possible and how can we do that?

I've tried xiinclude but it seems it doesn't work there...
I've seen  but I can't get how it works even with the odoo documentation.

I'm working on Odoo 10.

Cordially,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent is the `t-call` function or directive. `t-call` includes another template file. You can use it to wrap content which is commonly what the `website.layout` template is used for as demonstrated in the example below.

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="addon_name.template_name" name="Template Name">
            <t t-call="website.layout">
                <div>Hello World</div>
            </t>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

However you do not need to use it as a wrapper for content. You can use the directive as a means to include other templates in your existing template. Just like this.

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="addon_name.template_name" name="Template Name">
            <t t-call="website.layout">
                <t t-call="addon_name.top_section"/>
                <t t-call="addon_name.middle_section"/>
                <t t-call="addon_name.bottom_section"/>
            </t>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

For this to work you must have already defined your templates, in my example they would be top_section,middle_section, and bottom_section. Also observe how these templates do not include the wrapper for the `website.layout`. When including a sub template you do not want to include the `website.layout` template as it is meant to provide an overall structure for the webpage and is meant to be used as a wrapper for the rest of you content.

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="addon_name.top_section" name="Top Section">

                <div>Hello World</div>

        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

If you are inheriting from another template you must first tell the templating engine where you wish to inject your code. This is done using an `xpath` expression. There are many examples of `xpath` expressions in Odoo source code. Please review there or online. The example below is in response to comments made below which were specifically regarding a report template. When creating report templates you would not want to include the `website.layout` template. This is for a website view not a `qweb` report.

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="addon_name.template_name" inherit_id="addon_name.template_name">
            <xpath expr="//div[@class='class_name']" position="replace">
                    <t t-call="addon_name.top_section"/>
                    <t t-call="addon_name.middle_section"/>
                    <t t-call="addon_name.bottom_section"/>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: Where did you create your templates top_section,middle_section and bottom_section, I mean in which file and what to do with inherited files cause I got a an issue linked to that ,  t-call=" " can't be located in the parent view ...

Comment: http://prntscr.com/e0j3a2                                                   http://prntscr.com/e0j3fb there are my files

Comment: Because you are inheriting you need to first give your template a position in the parent template to inject your templates code. There is probably a real term to describe what I just said however I do not know what it is. I will update my code with an example of including another xml template in an inherited view. Looking at your example I think you need to just move your `t-call` inside your `xpath` expression.

Comment: The templates can be placed in one xml or multiple xml files. These files must be referenced in your __openerp__.xml or __manifest__.xml file. Once your addon has been updated Odoo will store these templates in the database so that when you reference them in your code it will find them and inject them into your template.

Comment: I made your change and now I got this error http://prntscr.com/e0mmet , I don't think it's worse than the other one but is my template "titi" defined as I did in my previous screenlink or do I have to touch in the addons file or something like that. For the record both of my xml files are placed in the same folder , I work on Odoo since a week it's not easy too understand the working... I put them in the manifest since start

Comment: I hear you. It can take a while to understand how the system works. I am still learning as well. It should not matter where your xml files are (as long as they are in your addon, and your __manifest__, or __openerp__ file properly point at them.  Try placing your addon name in front of the template name in your t-call. Could be a namespacing issue.

Comment: If you have properly loaded your templates into the system you should be able to find them in Settings/User Interface/Views

Comment: You can also verify the external_id. Which is what you should be referencing in your `t-call`

Comment: It worked and i put the name of the addon in front of the template name , thank you very much for your time, have a nice day!

Comment: Can you do me a favour and mark my answer as correct? Thanks! Glad I could help.

Comment: Done, I wish you a successful continuation.

Comment: Thanks Sacha. You too.